# How to use ng-translate with variables resolved from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ng-tranlate` for `i18n`.

I'd like to combine a translated label together with a variable resolved from controller binding. How can I achieve the following?

```
<div translate="my.lang.text">some more: {{controller.attribute}}</div>
```

This does not work, and ng-translate ignores any content between the divs. why?

Comment: In your example, is *"some more:"* the translation of `my.lang.text` ?

Comment: no. `my.lang.text` is the i18n label in language.js; `some more: ` is freetext to be shown between the translated label and the controller-resolved variable.

Comment: That implies that the "freetext" won't be translated, but maybe that's not a problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `translate` directive replaces all the element's content with the translation.

In this case, you probably want to use the translate filter instead.

```
<div>{{'my.lang.text' | translate}} some more: {{controller.attribute}}</div>
```

As an alternative, you could also avoid this issue by giving the translated value it's own element.

```
<div><span translate="my.lang.text"></span> some more: {{controller.attribute}}</div>
```

If the translation is always intended to have have a value appended to it, then using a parameterized translation is probably the best solution (as suggested by Michael https://stackoverflow.com/a/33419608/90305)

Answer (score 2):

The `translate` directive will replace the content of the element with the translation you pass to it.

The use case you are describing looks like a *parameterized translation*. If you want to keep the use of the directive, you could pass the variable through the `translate-values` directive:

```
<div translate="my.lang.text"
     translate-values="{value: 'some more: ' + controller.attribute}"></div>
```

You have to specify that your translation is parameterized:

**JSON**

```
"my.lang.text": "This is a parameterized string {value}"
```